# Как удалить ключи из массива?

Tags: php

имеется массив

```
$arr = array(
    '320',
    '256',
    '192',
    '160',
    '128',
    '64',
    '32',
    );
```

и переменная `$b = '192';` (значение всегда разное)
так вот, как из массива удалить ключи до 192, в данном случае 320 и 256

Comment: А как Вы попробовали решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://repl.it/DAU0/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При помощи `array_search()` находим индекс элемента, при помощи `array_splice()` удаляем элементы.

Comment: array_slice то что мне нужно